# Raspberry PI's wlan0 interface stops working after plugin a USB device

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, terminal, wifi-direct

I am working on a project with a ***raspberry pi 4B***, I am building a NAS drive out of a RPI, I have installed **samba, hostapd and dnsmasq** for my project. The hostapd is installed wlan0 interface and is accessible and visible in wifi as "PiServer". The HDD drive is mounted to the raspberry pi's /PiServer folder and can be accessed as in a normal network with samba, the ip is *192.168.4.1 and* is a static ip address.

The problem is that whenever I plug a USB device like a pendrive or a USB wifi adapter, ***the wlan0 interface goes down*** and is **no longer accessible** by the ssid showing under wifi nor with ssh with the IP address as well, the RPI requires to unplug the USB and restart the device twice in order to get the server working normal.

How can I fix this?
Appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Comment: What power supply are you using for your RPi4B, is it good for 5.1V @ 3A?

Comment: I use the original one that comes with RPI4B